# Nearby Places, Distance and Route between two places using Google Maps API for Web

Tags: google-maps, web, google-places-api

I am developing a website which uses Google Maps place API to get an area from the user and need to show nearest restaurants, hotels,etc.  I also need to show the distance and route between those places from the user selected area.

Can anyone help me to give some suggestions, links, or a tutorial to do that?

Comment: What language/platform you are using for web development?

Comment: I am using HTML, CSS, jquery and PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Well, I coundn't provide you all codes, but i can help you to build code, Kindly follow the following guidance. It might be help you.*

Basically you required two APIs for this solutions:

1) Google Directions API

2) Google Places API

3) Javascript - GEOLocation (auto detect user location, Works if website hosted with ssl cert - https )

**Step 1:**

Here first you need to detect user current location from browser (using HTML5 navigator.geolocation ):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

**Step 2:**

Now you required to search nearby hotels,restaurants, etc using Google Places API. Please check following doc where you can see that places api required location coordinates as a input and will respond you accordingly,

[Web Service API Doc](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) OR [JavaScript API Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search#try-it-yourself)

**Step 3:**

Directions API will works on between two points, So here it's better to build dynamic route between two Points (user location and particular restaurant/hotel/etc location) using [Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro). You can build route using marker click event.

[Google Direction API - Javascript Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple)

*I hope that i have tried to explain better as i can, Kindly ignore formatting and spelling mistakes, Just focus on step i given, Ignore other stuff!!*

Comment: Thank you so much Rajnish. It is very useful for me.